# Define metrizability weak*-topology of X*

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Weak *-topology of $X^*$ is metrizable if and only if …](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144475/weak-topology-of-x-is-metrizable-if-and-only-if)

Define metrizability weak*-topology of  $X^*$  which $X$ is T.V.S on which $X^*$ separates points.

Comment: Definition of metrizability of X*, no X

Comment: I stated the definition for a general topological space $X$.  Replace my $X$ by your $X^*$.

Comment: What you want is not completely clear. Do you want necessary/sufficient conditions on the space $X$ so that its dual $X^*$ with the weak* topology is metrizable? One well-known result is that the unit ball of $X^*$ is metrizable iff $X$ is separable, and the whole space is metrizable iff $X$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: @N.I: that's not true.  If $X$ has a countable Hamel basis, $X^*$ is metrizable.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: You're right, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A topology on $X$ is *metrizable* if there is a metric on $X$ which produces the same topology.