# Are the finite signed measures on a compact set $M(Compact)$ first countable?

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces

Let $M(Compact)$ be the set of finite signed measures on a countable set?
(with the topology generated by the sets $\left\{ \mu \in M(Compact) : \left| \int f(x)  \mu(dx)- a\right| \leq \delta\right\}$ for all $\delta>0$, $a \in R$ and $f \in C_b(Compact)$ (continuous and bounded). (hence weak-*-topology)

Is then $M(Compact)$ first countable?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not first countable as it is not metrizable. Some arguments are mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144475/weak-topology-of-x-is-metrizable-if-and-only-if), observing that $C_b(Compact)$ has an uncountable Hamel basis.

Comment: I thought metrizable is only sufficient for first countable and not necessary.... Am I wrong? If not, then you only show that it is not metrizable, but not that its not first countable...

Comment: In topological vector spaces, first countable and metrizable are equivalent. This follows from the fact that the system of 0-neighbourhoods defines the topology everywhere.